# Access Denied Message for new domain users in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a problem with the sharepoint server, I added 2 new domain users and they cannot access the sharepoint site ,they're getting the 'Access Denied' msg,although all users are given permissions to access the main website by default as soon as they're added to the domain

Any suggestions ?? or settings that i can check?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, check that they have a clean IE cache, have restarted their browser etc.

Check that they don't have an incorrect stored user name and password against the site host name on their Windows profile.

Ensure that the permissions on the site in question haven't been amended without your knowledge.

Ensure that they are in the correct AD group (if necessary)

Have a look at the IIS logs and ensure that their credentials are being passed in.  (Search for their username).  If they are not, you'll need to ensure that the SharePoint site is in the correct zone on their browser to get credentials passed in.  (Trusted sites?)

Have a look in the Windows Event Logs and ULS logs when they try to hit the site to see if anything unexpected is happening

Ensure that you don't have any Web Application policies set up (go to Central Admin -> Application Management --> Policy for web application) which would deny these specific users access.

Ensure that the user account directory path, and people picker settings for the site are not stopping them from getting access:

```
stsadm -o getsiteuseraccountdirectorypath -url <site url>           
stsadm -o getproperty -pn peoplepicker-seachadcustomfilter -url <site url>
```

Answer (score 3):

Sharepoint caches the domain user credentials, new users may not be available right away. Try checking the synchronization messages in "Central Administration" -> "Application Management" -> "Manage service applications" -> "User Profile service application" and maybe force a new synchronization.

Comment: I forgot to mention that am using Sharepoint 2007, I couldn't find the path you mentioned above,am trying to search how to force a new synch on 2007 but couldn't find the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You must set permissions for newly added domain user in sharepoint. Add it to a group that has permissions to read your root site. See permissions at url: http://server/_layouts/user.aspx